# One math problem for one row and 3 columns

Tags: r, math, series, arithmetic-expressions

I am a beginner and am confused; What I have so far

[image: What I have so far]

I am supposed to use this data to find:
3e^-x-y^5+2z

How do I combine all these math functions into one to solve?
I'm supposed to calculate that for each row it seems.

exp(-x)*3
figured this out for column x.

Comment: `file$answer = 3*exp(-file$x)-file$y^5+2*file$z`?

Comment: What does the $ do?

Comment: It said that 'e' was not found.

Comment: i created 'e' using something and it worked!

Comment: Not sure what materials you're working with, but `$` is how you access the named components of a list. In the example of a data frame, it's how you access a named column of the data frame. See chapter 6 here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: You could also do `with(file, 3*exp(-x) - y^5 +2*z)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.